# Problemas con Selenium WebDriver al permitir camara/notificaciones

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

al entrar a una web me pide que otorgue ciertos permisos como notificaciones, cámara... Para ello me sale la siguiente alerta. Como podría darle a la "X" para cerrarla, bloquearla o permitirla?

Muchas gracias de antemano!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

esto funciona para mi

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--use-fake-ui-for-media-stream")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```